# Bootstrap carousel controls aren't working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I have this carousel on my site:

```
<div id="carousel-container" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active"><img class="d-block w-100" src="comput.jpg" alt="Slide 1"/></div>
        <div class="carousel-item"><img class="d-block w-100" src="unity.jpg" alt="Slide 2"/></div>
        <div class="carousel-item"><img class="d-block w-100" src="my.jpg" alt="Slide 3"/></div>
    </div>

    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carousel-container" data-slide="prev" role="button">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carousel-container" data-slide="next" role="button">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

The carousel controls aren't working, I click on it and nothing happens. 
(Yes, I've already looked up to similar questions but the those solutions didn't work to me.)

Comment: Do you have the Bootstrap javascript loaded?

Comment: Omg, can't believe i forgot that. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will run after you use these js files.(using "bootstrap.js" or"bootstrap.min.js"). You can look the demo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Ercan Er</h2>  
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/m5d1FlSeF-M/maxresdefault.jpg" alt="Example 1" style="width:100%;">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/m5d1FlSeF-M/maxresdefault.jpg" alt="Example 2" style="width:100%;">
      </div>
    
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/m5d1FlSeF-M/maxresdefault.jpg" alt="Example 3" style="width:100%;">
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```